# Finding integer part of a polynomial root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If a polynomial $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x+5$ has only one real root $\omega$ then integer part of $\omega = -3$.

It appeared in my school exam and I couldn't solve it completely but somehow tried to find the range in which the root lies. But it was tough to show that $[\omega] = -3$.

Comment: Just a bad title. Please change it.

Comment: What is wrong in the title.I mean how does this title affects you in solving the problem. I will not change the title

Comment: Titles help people to find problems they are interested in. "Just a tough problem" doesn't fulfill that.

Comment: can't you see the tags ' polynomial'.

Comment: Have you given any thought what would this website look like if every user who had a "tough problem" would declare this fact in the title?????

Answer (score 2):

If this polynomial $P(x)$ has prospectively one real root between $-2$ and $-3$, we can show that easily.

$P(-3)=-7$ and $P(-2)=3$.  Since a polynomial is continuous, there must be a number, $\omega$ between $-3$ and $-2$ such that $P(\omega)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=3x^2+4x+1$

The derivative vanishes for $x=-1,-\frac{1}{3}$ It is positive for $x\in(-\infty,-1)$

$f(-3)=-7$

$f(-2)=13$

Thus, by the intermediate value theorem there must be a root in $(-3,2)$ such that $f(\omega)=0$. Thus, it has an integer part of $-3$

Comment: We are not allowed to use such derivatives in our school exam. I am in Std 8 and we have to use basic principles of polynomials

Comment: The root must be in $(-3,\color{red}-2)$. You didn't proove there is only one real root.

Comment: @MayankJha Oh, sorry then. It all holds without the derivative. I just, as Bernard, didn't read the "If" part. Since it's negative before -3 and positive after -2 then it must be equal to 0 between them, and we have only one root so yeah.

Bernard It is assumed that it only has one real root. Read the question well. It starts with "If".
 Of course the floor is meant. That is what i assumed at least.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(\infty)\to\infty,f(-\infty)\to-\infty,f(0)=5$$ Roughly sketch them:
[image]

Red one is possible since blue one has 3 roots. So it is now known that the root is negative.
Now sum of roots is $-2$, product of roots is $-5$, judging we get the roots is nearby $-1$ to $-10$ atmax. Try values at those x and see where it changes from positive to negative and between them form the graph there will be a root.